Как сделать, чтобы Telegram Bot постоянно отслеживал запрос с Django Rest Framework?
Вся суть в самом вопросе. При изменении данных в строке таблицы Django Rest Framework должен посылать запрос в Telegram Bot'а, он же в свою очередь постоянно это отслеживает. В случае если запрос есть, отправляет сообщение пользователю. Как лучше это реализовать? Или в целом сделать через цикл постоянное получение запроса при изменении статуса?

Добро пожаловать на сайт, user588484, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста со справкой как задать вопрос на ru.SO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Создайте сигнал, который будет реагировать на нужные изменения в таблице, в нем напишите функцию на aiogram или другой библиотеке, которая будет отправлять сообщение нужному пользователю.
